# What is the color format to use with imagerotate() in PHP?

Tags: php, function, colors

In PHP; what format is used for the background color option in the function imagerotate().

```
$color = "???????";
imagerotate($image, $degrees, $color);
```

I have tried:

```
$color = "#FFFFFF";
$color = "255255255";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to specify it with imagecolorallocate():

```
// sets some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

// hexadecimal way
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
```

via [the man pages](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
Example of USE as it is not given above......



    // File and rotation
    $filename = 'test.jpg';
    $degrees = 355;

    // Content type
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

    // Load
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);    
    $white = imagecolorallocate($source, 255, 255, 255);

    // Rotate
    $rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees,$white,0);

    // Output
    imagejpeg($rotate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to previouslly allocate the desired `$color` with **[`imagecolorallocate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php)** or **[`imagecolorallocatealpha()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocatealpha.php)**.

Answer (score 0):

if you making only 90, 180, 270 degrees rotations - the color doesn't matter - then you can use just:

```
imagerotate($image, $degrees, 0);
```

to avoid code mess (works with PHP 5.6.x)